# AngularJS + Gulp - Should I concatenate all files in one?

Tags: angularjs, build, gulp

I am giving the final details to my first AngularJS app and I am creating a Gulp config for uglifying my code and set some constants to get a cleaner way to define differents environments.

Now, this is my project folder structure with my components order by folder, so each component has a folder, so it's cleaner to my to develop as I have many components:

```
src                                     
├── app                                 
│   ├── app.js                          
│   ├── config.js                       
│   └── index.html                      
└── resources                           
│    └── [...3rd party libraries...].min.js
└── components
    ├── admin
    |     ├── users
    |     |     ├── users.list.controller.js
    |     |     └── users.list.view.html 
    |     └── areas
    |           ├── areas.list.controller.js
    |           └── areas.list.view.html
    ├── [...etc...]
    └── [...etc...]
```

Now as of my config in my index.html I have all these .js imported, for example:

```
<script src="components/admin/users/users.list.controller.js"></script>
<script src="components/admin/areas/areas.list.controller.js"></script>
```

The question is, should I concatenate all my components code in only one file? If so, how can I turn all my html js imports into only one (I'm asking for a automatized way, of course :))

If anyone has any thought on my app structure or standars, it's welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We usually decide to beak our bundle/minified file based on size. We use different approach in development and production environment.

**Development environment :**

- We use wiredep/gulp-inject to pass js files into index page.
- We put the watcher on wiredep/gulp-inject task to look into any change in the code. so that new code can be passed into index page automatically
- We use bower for client side dependencies and automate the process so that as soon as the dependency is installed the reference will go in index page.

**Production Environment**

- Bundle/Minify all the 3rd party library as a separate bundle.
- Bundle/Minify all the project files in separate bundle.
- Watch the size of these bundles frequently because as the code grows you might need to break the minified files into more files.
- We use grunt-usemin to serve the minified files

**References**

[Wiredep/gulp-inject](http://conan.is/bower/gulp/wiredep/javascript/2014/08/18/automating_linkage-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-build.html)

[usemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usemin)

Comment: I was reading and think that what I need is something like this. By now, I am editing the same js file as it's imported in the index, and not bypassing it with gulp.
But, the thing is, when you minified for production environment, you would need to change all the js path from dev to the "bundle.js". That's what I don not how to do..
<script src="/js/1.js"/>
<script src="/js/2.js"/>
<script src="/js/3.js"/>
to automatically <script src="/js/bundle.js"/>